# Grouped Bar Chart: Proper Alignment

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

I am new to matplotlib and I am having trouble creating a grouped bar chart. I read this [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) but I cannot find a way to properly align the bars so they do not overlap.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['tt.03', 'tt.03a', 'tt.06', 'stats.txt', 'sum.txt', 'minmax.txt']
fourthreads = [19.290, 17.861, 21.782, 49.188, 17.821, 75.593]
threethreads = [23.447, 22.125, 27.251, 62.778, 22.769, 95.78]
twothreads = [33.364, 31.793, 39.508, 89.716, 32.954, 137.475]
onethreads = [61.1, 58.074, 72, 163.335, 61, 248.597]

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.35 #width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects4 = ax.bar(x+width, fourthreads, width, label='4 Threads')
rects3 = ax.bar(x+width/2, threethreads, width, label='3 Threads')
rects2 = ax.bar(x-width/2, twothreads, width, label='2 Threads')
rects1 = ax.bar(x-width, onethreads, width, label='1 Threads')

ax.set_ylabel('Execution time in seconds')
ax.set_title('Execution time in seconds by thread and command')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
        xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
        xytext=(0,3),
        textcoords="offset points",
        ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()[enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw without overlapping by opening the x-axis spacing. It is adjusted at half the width to fit the memory.

```
x = np.arange(0,len(labels)*2, 2)
width = 0.35 #width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects4 = ax.bar(x+(width/2)*3, fourthreads, width, label='4 Threads')
rects3 = ax.bar(x+width/2, threethreads, width, label='3 Threads')
rects2 = ax.bar(x-width/2, twothreads, width, label='2 Threads')
rects1 = ax.bar(x-(width/2)*3, onethreads, width, label='1 Threads')
```

[image]

holizontal bar graph:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
rects4 = ax.barh(x+(width/2)*3, fourthreads, width, label='4 Threads')
rects3 = ax.barh(x+width/2, threethreads, width, label='3 Threads')
rects2 = ax.barh(x-width/2, twothreads, width, label='2 Threads')
rects1 = ax.barh(x-(width/2)*3, onethreads, width, label='1 Threads')

ax.set_xlabel('Execution time in seconds')
ax.set_title('Execution time in seconds by thread and command')
ax.set_yticks(x)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        width = rect.get_width()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(width),
                    xy=(width, rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2),
                    xytext=(25, -5),
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to have the annotations clearly laid out ? As it stands, it is too difficult to read them.

Comment: If the annotations overlap, a horizontal bar chart is recommended.

Comment: Is there a particular formula to set the gap between the bars, if we want to increase the number of bars per command, from 4 to 8 ?

Comment: `x+(width/2)*3`This is the point I wrote in the first code, so you can add up to 3,4,5.